# Using windowmaker with quartz-wm in proxy mode on Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, xorg

I can modify my `.xinitrc` file to exec `/opt/local/bin/wmaker`, and get WindowMaker 0.90.2 as my window manager in X11.app. I'd like to use quartz-wm not as a window manager, but to provide the pasteboard integration with Aqua using the `--only-proxy` flag (see the man page). If I add the following line to `.xinitrc`:

```
exec /usr/bin/quartz-wm --only-proxy &
```

then WindowMaker never starts, complaining that there's already a window manager running. Is it possible to get the two to play nicely together, or is proxy feature part of the Xquartz server now? It seems that the `Xquartz` manpage has a number of pasteboard-to-clipboard synchronisation settings, but it's not clear whether quartz-wm needs to be running for those to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute window manager after quartz-wm:

`/usr/bin/quartz-wm --only-proxy & exec /opt/local/bin/wmake`